# After published on playstore OTP not getting, but it works fine from Android Studio

Tags: java, android, firebase-authentication, google-play-services

Phone number verification still working fine with when I test from Android studio. But when I download from playstore, exception occured.

```
E/Volley: [42175] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyPhoneNumber?alt=proto&key=AIzaSyDrX17T8Q6wHJMzBNp6lpQgsezGLnEHio8
```

Also

```
07-21 18:14:31.581 30405-3770/? E/MyGcmListenerService: {"id":142420,"image_type":0,"image_url":"http://p16.muscdn.com/img/tos-maliva-p-0068/c9ec231abd7b46cf8ca36227615e2fad~c5_100x100.jpeg","open_url":"sslocal://aweme/detail/6572808861554576646?label=admin\u0026gd_label=click_push_recommend\u0026gid=6572808861554576646\u0026push_id=142420","text":"Beautiful wedding ","title":"","use_led":1}
07-21 18:14:31.581 30405-30405/? E/FirebaseInstanceId: Failed to resolve target intent service, skipping classname enforcement
07-21 18:14:31.591 30405-30405/? E/FirebaseInstanceId: Error while delivering the message: ServiceIntent not found.
07-21 18:14:
```

See: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jimmytrivedi.lapitchat

Comment: make sure google play signing is off , if it is on add google's SHA-1 code to your firebase

Comment: How can I check?

Comment: in the `google play console` from the menu find `app signing`

Comment: It is added, but why should I turn off? What is the use of that?

Comment: you cannot turn it off, it signs your apk before publish in store with another key , it use is for people who missing their keystore (all I can guess) , anyway if you are only using google api's it's good but if you want to use facebook or other companies api better not turn it on because this services will never work , i tried to get base64 hash of SHA-1 that google play gives to me but it's not same to hash that facebook(linkedin etc) api's getting from apk

Comment: Basically, what should I do now to remove this volley and other error? I'm not understanding your point, but really need your help.

Comment: i've seen OTP , this service get's your app's keystore hash right? , when google resigns your app this hash will change and the service verification will fail and wont work, you have to get SHA-1 hash from playstore and add it to OTP service to make it work

Comment: @ShayanD I don't know where is OTP service

Comment: you are using firebase OTP or other company??

Comment: @ShayanD I have exactly the same problem. I'm using firebase OTP

Comment: i've said in the comments what to do for fix, read all again @JimmyTrivedi

Comment: @ShayanD I'm sorry, but I read all comments, and I don't understand this comment: i've seen OTP , this service get's your app's keystore hash right? , when google resigns your app this hash will change and the service verification will fail and wont work, you have to get SHA-1 hash from playstore and add it to OTP service to make it work...Please tell me what should I do? once you'll help, you can post as an answer and I'll accept and upvote it. Thanks again.

Comment: @ShayanD please reply, I commented something on your posted answer. Also I upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 2):

first go to `google play console` and go to page described in image bellow
[image]

`App signing certificate` refers to key that your app is signed with in google play and `upload certificate` refers to key that your uploaded apk is signed with

copy SHA-1 certificate and go to your `firebase console` and then go to your project setting then add a new certificate SHA-1
[image]

paste your SHA-1 and press save and done

your problem should be fixed.

for more information you can read [this](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423).

Comment: Which certificate for Sha-1 choud I copy? App signing or upload?

Comment: ?should I delete the old firebase sha-1 key?

Comment: @jimmytrivedi better to keep both